# Como fazer mais de um select na mesma query em diferentes tabelas do BD?

Tags: php, query, mysqli, select

O problema é o seguinte:

Tenho as tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que são chaves estrangeiras na seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu preciso puxar todos os nomes das colunas "modelo_conector", "nome_genero_conector" e "tipo_de_conector" e concatenar e dar um echo em uma determinada busca.

Para isso, tentei fazer a seguinte consulta, mas não deu certo, pois necessita fazer vários selects na mesma query:
Obs: nessa tentativa eu só coloquei os selects das tabelas conectores_modelos, conectores_tipos e conectores, não consegui encaixar a tabela conectores_generos:

```
function listaConectores($conexao) {
$conectores = array();
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, 
"select
    c.*
    ct.tipo_de_conector as tipo_de_conector,
    temp_sql.modelo_conector
from
(select
    c.id_conector
    cm.modelo_conector
from
    conectores as c
join
    conectores_modelos as cm
on
    c.conectores_modelos_id_conector_modelo = cm.id_conector_modelo
)
    temp_sql
join
    conectores as c
on
    temp_sql.id_conector = c.id_conector
join
    conectores_tipos as ct
c.conectores_tipos_id_conector_tipo = ct.id_conector_tipo"
);
    while($conector = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    array_push($conectores, $conector);
}

return $conectores;
}
```

Porém, ele está me retornando sempre esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem uma sugestão ou uma luz que possa me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro parece estar na sua conexão com o banco de dados (imagino que seja pelo home do arquivo), precisaria mostrar o código nele pra confirmar. O seu select retorna os dados que você deseja se executa-lo no workbench (se for mysql) ou na ferramenta que use para consultar/manter seu banco de dados?

O select que esta fazendo seria para retornar algo assim:

```
select c.*, cm.modelo_conector, cg.nome_genero_conector, ct.tipo_de_conector
from conectores c
left join conectores_modelos cm on cm.id_conector_modelo = c.conectores_modelos_id_conector_modelo
left join conectores_generos cg on cg.id_conector_genero = c.conectores_generos_id_conector_genero
left join conectores_tipos ct on ct.id_conector_tipo = c.conectores_tipos_id_conector_tipo
```

Answer (score 1):

Não testei, mas creio que vc consegue resolver tudo com JOINS e não subselects.

Se obrigatoriamente na tabela conectores, sempre forem cadastrados um id de cada tabela creio que vá funcionar.

Tente

```
SELECT cm.modelo_conector, cg.nome_genero_conector, ct.tipo_de_conector
FROM conectores c
INNER JOIN conectores_modelos cm ON c.conectores_modelos_id_conector_modelo = cm.id_conector_modelo
INNER JOIN conectores_generos cg ON c.conectores_generos_id_conector_genero = cg.id_conector_genero
INNER JOIN conectores_tipo ct ON c.conectores_tipos_id_conector_tipo = ct.id_conector_tipo
```

Answer (score 1):

A sua função está causando um erro. Após chamar a função `mysqli_query` você pode chamar a função [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) para verificar se houve algum problema.

Quanto a sua consulta, sugiro utilizar um comando mais simplificado, como um `JOIN`.

Um exemplo simples de uso:

```
SELECT
  A.*,
FROM conectores AS A
LEFT JOIN conectores_modelos AS B
  ON (A..conectores_modelos_id_conector_modelo = B.id_conector_modelo)
LEFT JOIN  conectores_tipos as C
  ON (A.conectores_tipos_id_conector_tipo = C.id_conector_tipo);
```